# Adding a profile.html page on my project

Tags: python, django, django-views, user-profile

I have put a section on my website to fill a form of userprofile called profile.html . I have on this moment this models.py to display this information on my admin panel:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def url(self,filename):
    ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username,filename)
    return ruta

class userProfile(models.Model):    

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I want to enable the possibility of edit this information per user on their respective profile, thereby i can audit the user profile information per user in my admin panel (localhost:8000/admin) what is the good form to create the respective view and it url?

This is my urls.py actually (This isn't the main urls.py, is an especial urls.py for my app and lack the url for profile)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url


urlpatterns = patterns('',       

    url(r'^$','dracoin.apps.home.views.index' ,name='vista_principal'),
    url(r'^landing/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.landing' ,name='vista_aterrizaje'),
    url(r'^shop/page/(?P<pagina>.*)/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.shop' ,name='vista_tienda'),
    url(r'^card/(?P<id_tarj>.*)/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.singleCard',name='vista_single_card'),
    url(r'^contacto/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.contacto' ,name='vista_contacto'),
    url(r'^login/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.login_view',name='vista_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.logout_view',name='vista_logout'),
    url(r'^registro/$','dracoin.apps.home.views.register_view',name='vista_registro'),
```

This is my models.py for profile:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def url(self,filename):
    ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username,filename)
    return ruta

class userProfile(models.Model):    

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My views.py (lack the userProfile view)

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from dracoin.apps.synopticup.models import card
from dracoin.apps.home.forms import ContactForm,LoginForm,RegisterForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from dracoin.settings import URL_LOGIN
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout,authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, InvalidPage
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def index(request):
    return render_to_response('home/index.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required(login_url=URL_LOGIN)
def landing(request):
    return render_to_response('home/landing.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required(login_url=URL_LOGIN)
def shop(request,pagina):
    lista_tarj = card.objects.filter(status=True)
    paginator = Paginator(lista_tarj,5)
    try:
        page = int(pagina)
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        tarjetas = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage,InvalidPage):
        tarjetas = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    ctx = {'tarjetas':tarjetas}
    return render_to_response('home/shop.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required(login_url=URL_LOGIN)
def singleCard(request,id_tarj):    
    tarj = card.objects.get(id=id_tarj) 
    ctx = {'card':tarj}
    return render_to_response('home/singleCard.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))  

@login_required(login_url=URL_LOGIN)
def contacto(request):
    info_enviado = False # Define si se envio la informacion o no
    email = ""
    titulo = ""
    texto = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        formulario = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            info_enviado = True
            email = formulario.cleaned_data['Email']
            titulo = formulario.cleaned_data['Titulo']
            texto = formulario.cleaned_data['Texto']
            # Configuracion de enviado de correos vis hotmail
            to_supp = 'elzipa25@gmail.com'
            html_content = "Informacion recibida<br><br><br>***Mensaje***<br><h3>%s<h3><br><br>%s<br><br>%s"%(titulo,email,texto)
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Correo de Contacto',html_content,'from@server.com',[to_supp])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content,'text/html') # Contenido definido como html
            msg.send()
    else:
        formulario = ContactForm()                      
    ctx = {'form':formulario,'email':email, 'titulo':titulo, 'texto':texto, 'info_enviado':info_enviado}
    return render_to_response('home/contacto.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def login_view(request):
    mensaje = ""
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                next = request.POST['next']             
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                usuario = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
                if usuario is not None and usuario.is_active:
                    login(request,usuario)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
                else:
                    mensaje = "user or password aren't correct"
        next = request.REQUEST.get('next')      
        form = LoginForm()
        ctx = {'form':form,'mensaje':mensaje,'next':next}
        return render_to_response('home/login.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']            
            usuario = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password_one = form.cleaned_data['password_one']
            password_two = form.cleaned_data['password_two']

            u = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,username=usuario,email=email,password=password_one)
            u.save()
            return render_to_response('home/thanks_register.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            ctx = {'form':form}
            return render_to_response('home/register.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    ctx = {'form':form}
    return render_to_response('home/register.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Thanks!!

---

```
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    user_profile = user.userprofile

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_profile_form = userProfile(request-POST)
        if user_profile_form.is_valid():
            update user profile
    else:
        user_profile_form = userProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
    variables = RequestContext(request,{'user_profile_form' : user_profile_form})
    return render_to_response('home/edit_profile.html', variables)
```

Comment: do you want to edit user profile in admin panel?

Comment: I want to allow that each user edit their own profile. On this moment I already have the possibility to edit like a root all profiles of all users from my admin panel but I want to allow this task by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

1- Add this to `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^edit_profile/$', 'dracoin.apps.home.views.edit_profile', name='edit_profile'),
```

2- create a `form` and `user_profile` view in `views.py`:

```
# form
class userProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = userProfile

#view
def edit_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    user_profile = user.userprofile

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_profile_form = userProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_profile_form.is_valid():
            #update user profile
            user_profile.name = request.POST['name']
            user_profile.user = user
            user_profile.email = request.POST['email']
            user_profile.save()
    else:
        user_profile_form = userProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
    variables = RequestContext( request, {
        'user_profile_form': user_profile_form}
    )
    return render_to_response( 'edit_profile.html', variables )
```

3- Add `edit_profile.html` template:

```
<div> 
    <form  method="POST" action="."> 
        {% csrf_token %} 
            {{ user_profile_form.as_p }} 
        <input type="submit" name="edit_profile" value="Done"> 
    </form>        
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Hasan!! However I have a problem with the view on "if user_profile_form.is_valid(): update user profile, the debug page show me that i have a syntax problem in update user profile. What do you think?.

Comment: the traceback said me  that "update user profile" has a SyntaxError: SyntaxError at /edit_profile/

invalid syntax (views.py, line 120)

Comment: please update your answer. and put your `def edit_profile` in it? it is strange.

Comment: it's true! y copy bad the code excuse me, so i have a last mistake: **global name 'userProfileForm' is not defined**. This traceback report this line: `user_profile_form = userProfileForm(instance=user_profile)`, I respected the identation for all lines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64092/discussion-between-hasan-ramezani-and-jhonny).

Comment: put `userProfileForm` in your `views.py` from my answer.